# How to convert a sparse matrix into a list of triples

Tags: python, scipy

I have  a sparse matrix such as:

```
from scipy.sparse import random
from scipy import stats
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
rvs = stats.poisson(2).rvs
S = random(10, 10, density=0.25, random_state=rng, data_rvs=rvs)
S.A

array([[4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 3., 0., 0., 5.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 4., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 2., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2.]])
```

How can I convert S into a list of (row_id, col_id, value) triples.

In this case that would be:

```
[(0, 0, 4), (1, 1, 1), (1, 6, 3), (1, 7, 2), (2, 4, 1), (2, 6, 3)....]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the documentation is somewhat unhelpful, a "COO" format sparse matrix simply has `col`, `row`, and `data` lists which you can `zip()` through:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
coo = coo_matrix(array([[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[0,4,0]]))
coo_list = list(zip(coo.row, coo.col, coo.data))
print(coo_list)
```

produces

> ```
> [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (2, 1, 4)]
> ```